# django let's me save a model correctly via admin but not form/shell

Tags: django

I am having difficulty saving a Django model instance into my db. The instance consists of a FileField, which I think is what is causing the difficulty. My model is as follows:

```
class initial_settings(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    epsilon = models.FloatField(default = 0.3)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And when I open up a shell, create an instance, and save, I then run the command

```
test = initial_settings(name = 'test1234', epsilon = 3, document = 'doc.csv').save()
pd.DataFrame(csv.reader(open(test.document.path, 'r')))
```

Gives me an error, `No such file or directory` . But, if I open up the admin console and create an instance, it saves correctly and I am able to load it from shell. In the admin console, I can see that the instance created in shell is not being saved to the correct location ('media/documents') but instead direct to root dir, but I am not sure why. Any assistance is appreciated!

P.S:
Settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Edit: adding view and template:

views.py

```
FORMS_REG = [("doc_step1", Doc_form_1),
         ("doc_step2", Doc_form_2),
        ]         

TEMPLATES = {"doc_step1": "doc_step_1.html",
             "doc_step2": "doc_step_2.html",
             }
class Forecast_Wizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
            return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]


    instance = None
    
    def get_form_instance( self, step ):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = initial_settings()
        return self.instance

    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    
    def done(self, FORMS_REG, **kwargs):
        model_name = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('doc_step2')['name']

        self.instance.save()


        doc_obj = initial_settings.objects.get(name = name)

        return redirect('home')
```

templates (doc_step1 and doc_step2 use the same template code):

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!--Row with two equal columns-->

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1 col-sm-1">
           
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-sm-12">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p class = "card-text">Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
            {% for field in form %}
                {{field.error}}
            {% endfor %}
            <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <table>
            {{ wizard.management_form }}
            {% if wizard.form.forms %}
                {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
                {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                    {{ form }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                {{ wizard.form }}
            {% endif %}
            </table>
            {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
            <button name="wizard_goto_step" class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">first step</button>
            <button name="wizard_goto_step" class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">prev step</button>
            {% endif %}
            <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" value="submit"/>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xl-1 col-sm-1">
           
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: remove the slash in upload_to='documents' and then try

Comment: and from here to MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: if you still get error add your form , template  and view

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Blackranger, I made those changes and am still getting the same behavior. I am using the Django formwizard, so I can post my templates but there will be two of them. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I added the views and templates, let me know if any other info would be helpul

Comment: Here is `FileField` and `FilePathField` in Django. So document must be file-like object and not `string` type `'doc.csv'` variable (I guess). Are you sure that Django automatically handles is `document` a path or file object?

Comment: I am uploading a csv here. And I used similar code in another project which works fine. The fact that I can create and upload a document from the admin area and not shell makes me think there is some filepath or directory error in the code

Comment: When I attempt to upload from the form wizard (in the app itself), I click the dropdown and select my documents, but then when I click "next" it gives an error "this field is required"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, was a pretty simple error. The form type on my template was wrong. I needed

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

instead of just

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```